# Translating Section of an Italian Almanac

Tags: translation, abbreviations

I am doing research on an ancestor (or relative of my ancestor) and found his name in two Italian almanacs. Using Google Translate I have figured out most of what I want to know, but not all of it. Here are some words and abbreviations that Google Translate apparently can't help me with. Hopefully someone here can.

### Abbreviations

- Vesc.

### Words

- NAPOLETANE
- Aquino
- Sora

Do note that these are related to the Catholic Hierarchy.

Here is (in its original Italian) what the [text](https://books.google.com/books?id=osATAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA334&lpg=PA334#v=onepage&q&f=false) said:

> ## Gerarchia Cattolica
>
> ### Arcivescovi e Vescovi delle Sedi Residenziali italiane.
>
> ...
>
> #### PROVINCIE NAPOLETANE
>
> ...
>
> Vesc. Aquino — Raffaele Sirolli.
>
> Pontecorvo (Antichi dominii della S. Sede) e Sora — Raffaele Sirolli.

Perhaps you guys can help me translate this and help me learn about my ancestor (or relative of my ancestor) - Raffaele Sirolli.

Comment: Was your ancestor a Catholic bishop? I was under the impression they could not have children.

Comment: I think either he is an ancestor or a relative of an ancestor. I have only recently started my research.

Comment: The words that Google translate does not translate are, with the only exception of *napoletane*, nouns and toponyms (that is place names) so they cannot be translated

Comment: I guess that Arciv. is an abbreviation of Arcivescovo (Archbishop) while Vesc. is the abbreviation of Vescovo (Bishop).
Without a more clear context, I could not understand what Imm. Sogg. could stand for, the only thing I could say is that the double consonant (_mm_ and _gg_) suggests that those are abbreviations of plural words

Comment: I did a little more research while I waited for replies and found out that "Imm. Sogg. - Arciv. Amalfi — Enrico De Dominicis" are not important for my research. It is about someone else. Gonna remove it.

Comment: I also added a link to the almanac.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The completely spelled out version of “Imm. Sogg.” is “[immediatamente soggetta](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diocesi_immediatamente_soggetta_alla_Santa_Sede)” (it refers to a diocese, so it's feminine). It means that the diocese is directly dependent from the Holy See, and not from a Metropolitan Bishop, in which case it would be a “diocesi suffraganea” ([suffragan diocese](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffragan_diocese)).

The abbreviations “Vesc.” and “Arciv.” mean “vescovo” (bishop) and “arcivescovo” (archbishop).

“Napoletane” is “Neapolitan”, that is, “related to Naples”. “Enrico de Dominicis” is a person's noun; Amalfi Sora and Aquino are toponyms.

Apparently, your ancient relation was the bishop of [Pontecorvo](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pontecorvo). The town used to be an exclave of the Papal State inside the Kingdom of Naples.